# Constraint Layout can't set width or height to 0

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, layoutparams

How can i set real width or height to **0** in `ConstraintLayout` programatically via its `LayoutParams` since the fact that `ConstraintLayot.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT = 0` ?

I want to use in my code something like this:

```
view.getLayoutParams().width = 0;
view.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround for this.
So according to this

```
<attr name="layout_height" format="dimension">
        <!-- The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding).
             This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and
             is replaced by {@code match_parent}. -->
        <enum name="fill_parent" value="-1" />
        <!-- The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding).
             Introduced in API Level 8. -->
        <enum name="match_parent" value="-1" />
        <!-- The view should be only big enough to enclose its content (plus padding). -->
        <enum name="wrap_content" value="-2" />
    </attr>
```

**-1** is used for **match_parent**

and

**-2** is used for **wrap_content**

so we can use **-3** for setting 0 or less than 0 value for width or height.

e.g.

```
android:layout_width="-3dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

this is example code to try, it works for me

```
val params = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT,
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
                val space16 = binding.root.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.space_16)
                params.setMargins(space16, 0, 0, 0)

                /*app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imgIcon1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"*/

                params.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
                params.endToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
                params.startToEnd = binding.imgIcon1.id
                params.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID


                binding.containerBottom.layoutParams = params
```

Answer (score -1):

If by "height" you mean the absolute top-to-bottom dimension of the ImageView, you can do the following to double to height of an ImageView. You can set height to the value that you want.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); 
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) 
iv.getLayoutParams(); lp.height = 0 ; iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

See ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: I want to make it really 0

Answer (score -2):

if you want change width to `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` you need set layout with horizontal constraint

`layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` or `layout_constraintStart_toEndOf`

and

`layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` or `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf`

Comment: Where did i say that i want to set it as MATCH_CONSTRAINT? 

I want to set to 0...

Comment: ya you need set both layout_constraintStart_toStartOf & layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf then the MATCH_CONSTRAINT can works